# Require program to run as admin

Tags: c, windows-7, admin

How can I check if my program is running as an administrator on a Windows 7 system, using C?

In batch I could do something along the lines of:

```
whoami /groups | findstr /b /c:"Mandatory Label\High Mandatory Level" | findstr /c:"Enabled group" > nul: && set IS_ELEVATED=1
    if %IS_ELEVATED%==0 (
        set /p _="You need to run Utilis as administrator, run with admin cmd. Press enter to exit..
    )
```

This will check if the current user is an administrator or not. How can I achieve the same concept in C?

Comment: By setting the executable's properties so that it can only be run by administrator?

Comment: @WeatherVane That could work, is there a way I could do it from within the program itself?

Comment: Sorry, never tried that.

Comment: @WeatherVane all good, post the exec properties as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that if you set the executable's properties and permissions, so that it can *only* be run by administrator, that could solve the problem.